# Zapier: Extracting from a JSON array that is stored in MySQL Database with Python Code

Tags: python, json, zapier

I am new to coding in Zapier and Python, especially with JSON arrays.

I am storing a JSON array in a MySQL field. The can access the field that contains the JSON data in Zapier.

[Here is the JSON array in Zapier Zap](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4gripOURwAmADvQuDWAVNhyM0SIdky9/view?usp=sharing).

If would like to extract the value of postcode from this JSON Array using pyhton.

[Here is the code I have so far.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HoYRlx5H0hgVyC9LwLvFXF__eWC4gzv2/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a view of the JSON Array as decoded by http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode

[Extract of the JSON Array Data.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15IogBJpNh20Em_hA-0FiAmGDnlr2m7tF/view?usp=sharing)

Any assistance would be appreciated. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Can you paste the actual json you're working with in the question instead of the image of the text?

Comment: Xavdid. The code I have so far is in the second hyperlink in the original post.

Comment: Right but it's much easier to see the structure of the JSON when it's formatted instead of all together. Is postcode at the top level?

Comment: xavdid. The decoded JSON array have been added to the question. The value of postcode appears to be a top level value. Thanks for your assistance so far.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! So you're very close. The problem is that you've got a newline before the data you're returning, so Python returns nothing.

If you have something to this effect, it'll work:

```
import json

j = json.loads(input_data['json_data'])
return {'postcode': j['postcode']}
```

As a side note, for future questions, please post details as text rather than images. If your code was more than a few lines or your json was more complicated, having to re-type data out of an image would have been **incredibly** frustrating.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. if this worked for you, make sure to upvote answer and select is as having solved your problem.